# static method calls Toast.makeText

Tags: android

I have a thread running in C++, it will call my UI thread's (Java) static method when some condition's satisfied. When the static method was called, I want a Toast to show on my UI. What I have tried are:

1

```
     static void myMethod(){
        Toast.makeText(context, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        (I have a static context reference in global scope)
     }
```

RESULT:

```
     E/AndroidRuntime( 1331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

2

```
     static void myMethod(){
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
             public void run(){
                Toast.makeText(Context, "message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });
```

RESULT:

```
   Can not compile: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method runOnUiThread(Runnable) from the type Activity
```

Can anybody throw some light on this? Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are calling this method from a different thread than the UI thread and this causes an Exception. I have just tried declaring a static method in my Application class that would do the same as your first code. It worked - but of course only when called from main UI thread.

If you would like to be able to call the static method from a different thread, then you will need to create a handler on the UI thread to display the Toast. Something like this:

```
private static final int MSG_SHOW_TOAST = 1;

private static Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
       public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
           if (msg.what == MSG_SHOW_TOAST) {
               String message = (String)msg.obj;
               Toast.makeText(App.this, message , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
};

private static void displayMessage() {
   Message msg = new Message();
   msg.what = MSG_SHOW_TOAST;
   msg.obj = "Message to show";
   messageHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}
```

The context in my sample is retrieved from App.this, which is the Application class. You can replace this with your Activity, or your static global context.

Comment: Thanks, this is the perfect simple tutorial on how to use handlers. Was looking for this everywhere

Comment: I get a "No enclosing instance of the type Application is accessible in scope" compile error.

Answer (score 6):

```
static Activity thisActivity = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    thisActivity = this;    
}

public static void showMsg()
{       
  Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "message" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: you can remove `thisActivity` and use `getApplicationContext()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, as described in [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) post:

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

  /**
   * Instances of static inner classes do not hold an implicit
   * reference to their outer class.
   */
  private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<SampleActivity> mActivity;

    public MyHandler(SampleActivity activity) {
      mActivity = new WeakReference<SampleActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      SampleActivity activity = mActivity.get();
      if (activity != null) {
        // ...
      }
    }
  }

  private final MyHandler mHandler = new MyHandler(this);

  /**
   * Instances of anonymous classes do not hold an implicit
   * reference to their outer class when they are "static".
   */
  private static final Runnable sRunnable = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() { }
  };

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Post a message and delay its execution for 10 minutes.
    mHandler.postDelayed(sRunnable, 600000);

    // Go back to the previous Activity.
    finish();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a slightly different method to get the context.

**Previously created global Application class:**

```
package com.com.YourAppName;

import android.app.Application;

public class YourAppName_app extends Application {

    //declarations, getters, setters, etc...
}
```

**A static method inside your Activity/FragmentActivity where you want the Toast:**

```
public class Home extends FragmentActivity {

static YourAppName_app app;

private static void yourStaticMethod() {

    app = ((YourAppName_app)getApplicationContext()); //can also call this in onCreate 
    Toast.makeText(app, "Your Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
}
```